# Cannot connect to EC2 Instance through SSH (Connection timed out)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance in AWS and running normally before. But today I can't connect into SSH and get response "Connection timed out".

I was search and what I get just about security group issue. In my case, SSH is enable to connect in inbound rule setting. And I also try to create new instance using same security group, it works fine.

Comment: A few silly questions - are you using the right credentials? The EC2 instance is up and running?

Comment: Make sure you first follow the steps from docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html

Answer (score 1):

If you stopped and restarted your instance check the public IP of the instance, as it would have changed.